# How to trigger anchor tag :target action even at same position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, anchor

I have some anchor tags that glow in yellow for 3 seconds and fadeout when they are clicked upon.

Here is my css:

```
.highlight:target {
    animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /***Transition delay 3s fadeout is class***/
    -moz-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadeoutBg {
    from {
        background-color: yellow;
    } /** from color **/
    to {
        background-color: lightgray;
    } /** to color **/
}
```

However, this target animation only triggers if I am not at the same level as the anchor tag.

For example:

```
<a href="#first">First</a>

<div class="highlight" id="first">Target</div>
```

If I click on the link `<a>`, it redirects me to the position of Target, and shows the yellow fadeout effect on the `<div>`. However, if I click on the href link again, no effect is shown presumably since I am already at the corresponding anchor position. Is there any way to trigger the yellow fadeout effect even if I just clicked on the href and I am at the same level as the anchor tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript, to trigger the reflow, between removing and re-adding the class name

```js
a = document.getElementById("a");

a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;

  div = document.querySelector(".highlight");

  div.classList.remove("highlight");



  void div.offsetWidth;  //The Reflow

  div.classList.add("highlight");
}, false)
```

```css
.highlight:target {
  animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /***Transition delay 3s fadeout is class***/
  -moz-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadeoutBg {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  } /** from color **/
  to {
    background-color: lightgray;
  } /** to color **/
}
```

```html
<a id="a" href="#first">First</a>

<div class="highlight" id="first">Target</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Will this above method work if there are multiple HTML tags with the highlight tag? I have several anchor tags which have unique IDs but the same classname. Should I proceed to just remove the id tag and add it back again then?

Comment: Can you clarify one doubt for me? Are there multiple  `a` tags, each having a separate highlight div as href or you want to play animation on more than one highlight divs, from single `a` tag?